# change font size of Chrome bookmarks panel

Tags: google-chrome

bookmarks bar doesn't zoom in with page zooming or minimal font setting in chrome.

So is there a way to increase font size for bookmarks bar?

Answer (score 4):

In XP you can change font size of bookmarks and tabs of the chrome by changing the `Message Box` value in display properties menu;

```
Control Panel -> Display -> Appearance -> Advanced -> Item -> Message Box
```

Comment: The same is true for Windows 7. For newer Windows versions it would also work but the settings are not available via GUI, so you either have to use the registry or 3rd party tools to do it.

Comment: Changing font size for message box changes font size for bookmarks only directly on bookmarks bar. If you have folders on bookmarks bar with bookmarks in them, and you want to increase font size for these bookmarks, then you must also change font size for "Menu Bar" item

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to change the **chrome bookmark bar font size** using the "chrome browser settings", but I'm not entirely sure.  **Alternatively**, use the "OS settings".  These settings are usually found in categories named: visual, appearance, theme, font size, etc... and can
be adjusted on either a specific or global scale.

**OS (Windows 10)**

1. **Start > Settings > Make text size bigger**
2. Start > Settings > Change the size of text, apps, and other items > Scale and layout
3. Start > Settings > Make everything bigger > Make everything bigger

Answer (score 0):

On Google Chrome click on 3 dots on upper right hand corner and scroll down to settings.  Settings>Advanced>Accessibility>Manage Accessibility Features>Display>Open Display Settings>Display Size>(Move bar towards middle of Tiny and Huge or to your liking)

Answer (score 0):

For windows 11...

1. select windows start button
2. type font in search bar
3. choose "make text size bigger"
4. Use scale to increase text size according to your preference, select apply
5. THENNNN, use the magnifier (upper right icon in url bar or use CTRL and -) to reduce the size of your screen from 100%

Not ideal fix, but a temporary solution that worked for me!

Answer (score -2):

Its so easy dear. Just type the following in your chrome browser:

chrome://flags

Now scroll down untill you find the option "HiDPI Support Windows".

Once you found the option change it from Default to Engable and then click on relunch now. You are done your from now your bookmark toolbar icons will be big.

Comment: it messes the whole browser up,it zooms pages including images into large mode not just the browser and this can't be undone, mouse context menu appears not where I clicked, living nightmare - not a solution.

Answer (score -9):

Click on bookmarks.
On top of the bookmark list, click Bookmark Manager.
Then simply use the Ctrl and + or _ to increase or decrease font size.
Alternately, press Ctrl and roll the mouse wheel.

Comment: This has nothing to do with enlarging bookmarks menu on "most opened websites" new page of chrome